# region in which the series is uniformly convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Just a general question. Suppose we have a series, in order to determine the region in which the series is uniformly convergence, is it correct to find the radius of convergence, then check whether the series converges or not on the radius? If the logic is wrong, please do correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's a power series with finite nonzero radius of convergence $R$, it always converges uniformly on $|z| \le r$ if $r < R$, and it converges uniformly on $|z|\le R$ if it converges absolutely at $|z|=R$.  If it doesn't converge absolutely at $|z|=R$, things might be more delicate.

Comment: Dear @Robert, thanks for the quick reply. In regard to your explanation, is that equivalent of saying the power series always converges uniformly on $|z| < R$, however in order to confirm whether one converges uniformly on $|z| = R$ or not, we must check if one converges absolutely at $|z| = R$ first. Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, it does not always converge uniformly on $|z|<R$.  As I said, it converges uniformly on $|z| \le r$ if $r < R$.

Comment: Also, it is possible that the series converges uniformly on $|z|\le R$ without converging absolutely there.

Comment: Dear @Robert, thanks for the clarification. In regard to your answer, you mentioned assuming the power series has finite nonzero radius of convergence $R$, what would happen if the radius of convergence $R=0$? Would that mean the series diverges everywhere except the origin?

Comment: Yes, if $R=0$ the series diverges everywhere except at the origin.